# Why 1 isn’t $a*b=max(a,b)$ identity element?

Tags: algebraic-groups, binary-operations

I had an exam this morning and the first question was in a test form ,the question goes:

Imagine there is a binary operation $a*b=max(a,b)$ on N . Which option is correct ?

a)$(N,*)$ is not abelian.
**which is obviously wrong**

b)$(N,*)$ has an identity element.

c)(N,*) has associative property.
**which is obviously right**

d)(N,*) is a group.
**which is not right.**

C is obviously right so this makes b wrong
But why ?
Isn’t 1 an identity element for this binary operation?

Comment: Is $N$ the natural numbers? Does it include $0$?

Comment: @Rammus   Though, if $0\in \mathbb N$ then $0$ is an identity element under $*$.

Comment: @Rammus its N .it doesn’t

Comment: @Negar  People disagree as to whether or not $0$ should be included in the natural numbers.  But this doesn't really matter as to your question.  The least element in $\mathbb N$ is an identity element under $*$, be that $1$ or $0$.

Comment: @lulu so this test is basically wrong ? I was thinking that if we say $a\le b$ b*a=b and also b*1=b . But identity element should be the only element with this property.

Comment: Either the test makers made a mistake, or you were actually supposed to choose more than 1 answer in that part of the test, imo.

Comment: @Divide1918 absolutely sure it wasn’t the second case.

Comment: Why does C) make B) wrong?  Strikes me that for $\min \mathbb N$ we'd always have $\max(\min\mathbb N, b) = b$ because $b \ge \min\mathbb N$.  So $\min \mathbb N$ will be an identity element.  Whether $\min \mathbb N=0$ or $\min \mathbb N= 1$ isn't that important but $*$ has an identity.  But why one earth would $*$ being associative rule that out.  Obviously there are associative operations with identities?  Multiplication and addition are obvious examples.

Comment: @Negar b) only asserts the existence of an identity element, not its uniqueness. In a group the identity element is unique, but the question did not state that $(\Bbb N,*)$ is a group.

Comment: @fleablood I think OP meant that by process of elimination, if c is right then b must be wrong.

Comment: @fleablood cause the question was in a test form and only one option could make it through:)) thanks for the explanation tho

Comment: @Divide1918 Thank you so much for your consideration <3

Comment: " But identity element should be the only element with this property." 1)That's not the definition of identity.  In a group the identity element can be proven to be unique but that isn't the definition of identity.  2) This *is* unique for every element.  If $1 < a \le b$ then $a*b = b$ but if $1\le c < a$ then $a*c \ne c$ so $a$ is not an identity.

Comment: @fleablood thank you so much for your time explaining this to me <3

Comment: Another possibility: Your teacher is being extremely pedantic so a) is actually right because "abelian" is used to describe groups but $(N,*)$ isn't a group, AND they made a mistake in the question statement, i.e. they intended to write "not correct" instead of "correct" (or you misread it yourself). Either way, in this case, the answer would then be (d).

Comment: @Divide1918 oh :,))))

Comment: @Divide1918 Although not very common, "abelian monoid" and "abelian semigroup" do occur in the literature.